# How do I save an image link into a list?

Tags: javascript, html, list

I'm trying to save an image link into a list so as to pass the variable to js as an item.

This is the image link:

```
<img src="{{=URL('static','images/3.jpg')}}" style="max-height='100px';border-radius:7px;"/>

I tried using:

lst = ["""<img src="{{=URL('static','images/3.jpg')}}" style="max-height='100px';border-radius:7px;"/>"""]
```

but something is just not right.

Howcan I achieve this?

Regards

Comment: use `` instead of "

Comment: Can you please write what is your desire output? Do you want
lst = ["{{=URL('static','images/3.jpg')}}"] ??? or the whole element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your element contains double quotes, you should escape them with backslashes:

```js
lst = ["<img src=\"{{=URL('static','images/3.jpg')}}\" style=\"max-height='100px';border-radius:7px;\"/>"]

console.log(lst[0]);
```